Azure Databricks Single Node Cluster 140 GB, 72 cores, Databricks Runtime version 12.2 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)
I have a dataframe with 330 (312 numeric) columns and 300,000 rows and I am trying to impute the medians, but memory utilization is maximized and it cannot finish.
median_values={col:df_new.approxQuantile(col,[0.5],0.01)[0] for col in df_new.colums}                                                  
batch_size=52
columns=list(median_values.keys())

for i in range(0,len(columns),batch_size):
    for col in batch:
        approx_med=median_values[col]         
 ```````df_new=df_new.withColumn(col,F.when(df_new[col].isNull(),approx_med).otherwise(df_new[col]))
       
 ```````df_new.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(f"/dbfs/tmp/intermediate_batch{i}")
        df_new=spark.read.parquet(f"/dbfs/tmp/intermediate_batch{i}")
        spark.catalog.clearCache()

The cluster settings are: spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled true / spark.master local[*, 4] / spark.databricks.cluster.profile singleNode / spark.sql.catalogImplementation unity
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

You can try the below methods to optimize the performance and memory utilization.

persist() - This can store the dataframe in memory, in disk or in both. Use persist() on your df_new dataframe and set the storage level as MEMORY_AND_DISK. This will store the dataframe in memory, but if there is not enough memory, it will split the data into the disk.
df_new.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

As your operations on the dataframe involves multiple re-computations, persists can save memory. You can unpersist() the data after the usage.

You can try by skipping the reading of the same dataframe result. This can reduce the I/O overheads.

You can enable Adaptive Query execution in this case. This can dynamically shuffle the partitions during the approxQuantile() transformation.
Use the below code to enable this.
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true")


If writing to parquet type files is not necessary, use delta tables which are better for the large dataframes instead of parquet files.

Try with multi-node cluster.


If still it is giving the same outcome, check the monitoring and logs of the databricks to find out the code which causes memory shortage and try to modify it.

Thank you Rakesh for the suggestions. I tried persisting the dataframe to memory and disk, adaptive query execution and also removing unnecessary temporary views but the memory fills up to the max even when I try to impute the median for just one column. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

The only possible suggestion I can give is to try with a multi-node cluster.
